# Java Browser library

Tags: java, browser, proxy, webview, gecko

I need to implement a simple browser in java. I've been researching several possibilities including JxBrowser, JBrowser, JavaFX (WebEngine + WebView), among others. JxBrowser has potential but it's a paid library, which I would like to avoid.

This browser needs to be able to process all web functionalities including JavaScript and HTML5 while capable of connecting through proxies. Therefore the best solution may be to use a web engine like Gecko.

So I'd like some advice on libraries which are capable of implementing Gecko engine (including XULRunner) with the possibility of changing core Gecko preferences.
Also, if you know any other possible solution that doens't include Gecko, feel free to discuss.

Comment: This question may be [too open ended for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Why so? Hes trying to implement a real custom browser in java, and his facing doubts on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [SWT Browser widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html)?

For proxy in SWT Browser, see [How do I set a proxy for the Browser to use?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserproxy),

Comment: My objective is, if possible, configure proxy settings directly on Gecko. SWT information is very old and possible not working with new XULRunner versions.
"The SWT Browser widget embeds a platform's popular HTML rendering engine: Internet Explorer on a Microsoft® Windows® platform, Mozilla on Linux®, Safari on the Mac."
Also, I would like to choose which engine to use.

Comment: Read more about it, may be a solution. Will try it and give feedback.

Comment: Worked well, managed to implement SWT with XULRunner 1.9. Gecko preferences accessible so proxy will be changed internally.

Comment: :) Good for you. Not for nothing is part of Eclipse.